# If I entered the SWIFT code of a branch in another state, will I receive my wire transfer?

Tags: india, wire-transfer, swift

I live in Madhya Pradesh, India.  While entering the SWIFT code on my AdSense account, I used the SWIFT code of a bank branch in other state. My local branch does not have SWIFT code.

My account details are correct but the SWIFT code that I used belongs to the Kolkata Branch in West Bengal which is more than 2,000 km away from where I live.

It's the same bank.  Do I have to visit Kolkata to deal with this issue?  The  trip will cost more than the amount of wire transfer or will a visit to my local branch help?

Comment: Have you called your bank to ask? The answer likely depend on whether the bank is reusing account numbers between branches, or an account number is always unique among all the bank's customers. (You might be able to get a general-ish answer from someone who knows how banks in India usually do such things, but in that case you should add an [tag:india] tag to the question. Even so, the best chance of the answer being right would be if you reveal which bank it is)

Comment: So, Its STATE BANK OF INDIA. I contacted my branch a week ago, they suggested me to wait for some more time and to contact customer care. When I contacted customer care yesterday they suggested me to contact my branch. So I'll be visiting them again.

Answer (score 2):

It generally doesn't matter. Most branches do not have SWIFT Code. They would recommend using the SWIFT code of the main branch. As SBI has moved to Core Banking System; all the messages would arrive centrally and they will be able to credit your account.

Comment: Yes, they already did 2 days later but there was no sms alert. I checked my statement and found it.